# How to count the number of unique values efficiently in a repeated computation?

Tags: r, dplyr, unique

This is my transaction data

```
from_id       to_id      date_trx      week    amount
<fctr>        <fctr>     <date>        <dbl>   <dbl>
6644           6934       2005-01-01    1      700
6753           8456       2005-01-01    1      600
9242           9333       2005-01-01    1      1000
9843           9115       2005-01-01    1      900 
7075           6510       2005-01-02    1      400 
8685           7207       2005-01-02    1      1100   

...            ...        ...           ...    ...

9866           6697       2010-12-31    313    95.8
9866           5992       2010-12-31    313    139.1
9866           5797       2010-12-31    313    72.1
9866           9736       2010-12-31    313    278.9
9868           8644       2010-12-31    313    242.8
9869           8399       2010-12-31    313    372.2
```

I want to count the number of unique `to_id`s for each `from_id`s at each `week`: That is:

```
data <- data %>% 
  group_by(week,from_id) %>% 
  mutate(weekly_distinct_accounts=n_distinct(to_id))
```

But, it seems like computation will never end. What is the efficient way to do this? I also tried other functions [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056465/count-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-vector), but they couldn't be helpful either

Comment: Maybe `aggregate(to_id ~ from_id + week, data, function(x) length(unique(x)))`?

Comment: Try `data.table` : `setDT(data)[, .(weekly_distinct_accounts=uniqueN(to_id), .(week,from_id)]`

Comment: Thanks @GKi, it's the fastest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to store the result in `data` you can use `ave`.

```
data$weekly_distinct_accounts <- ave(data$to_id, data$from_id, data$week
  , FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

or using `duplicated`

```
data$weekly_distinct_accounts <- ave(data$to_id, data$from_id, data$week
  , FUN=function(x) sum(!duplicated(x)))
```

In case you just need the sum per group you can use `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(to_id ~ from_id + week, data, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

or

```
aggregate(to_id ~ from_id + week, data, function(x) sum(!duplicated(x)))
```

or

```
aggregate(to_id ~ ., unique(data[c("to_id", "from_id", "week")]), length)
```

Comment: This again takes so long to compute, aggregate() is way faster.

Comment: But do you want to store the result in `data`? If not then `aggregate` and co. will be good. If yes you have to use something like `ave`.

Comment: I added the result into the data by merge()